# Is there equivalent for __toString() method for other simple types in PHP?

Tags: php, function, types, magic-methods, object-to-string

_toString() is called when an object is used as string. How can I do something similar for numerical values, something like __toInt(), or __toArray(). Do such methods exist? Is there a work around? Is it a bad idea to use something like that even if there is a workaround for it?

Comment: Simply put, no there isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `__toArray` magic-method (just [check the ones that exist here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)), but then, there shouldn't be, IMO.
Though people have asked for a magic `toArray` method, it doesn't look like such a method will be implemented any time soon.

Considering what objects are for, and how we use them, a `toInt` method wouldn't make much sense, and since all objects can be *cast to an array*, and can be iterated over, I see very little point in using `__toArray` anyway.
To *"convert"* on object to an array, you can use either one of the following methods:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->foo = 'bar';
var_dump((array) $obj);
//or
var_dump(json_decode(json_encode($obj), true));
```

This can be done with both custom objects, as `stdClass` instances alike.
As far as accessing them as an array, I can't see the point. Why write a *slow* magic method to be able to do something like:

```
$bar = 'foo';
$obj[$bar];
```

if you can do:

```
$obj->{$bar}
```

or if you can do:

```
foreach($obj as $property => $value){}
```

Or, if you need something a tad more specific, just implement any of the `Traversable` interfaces.
And for those rare cases, where you want an object to produce an array from specific properties in a very particular way, just write a method for that and call that method explicitly.

```
class ComplexObject
{
    private $secret = null;
    private $childObject = null;
    public $foo = null;
    //some methods, then:
    public function toArray()
    {//custom array representation of object
        $data = array();
        foreach($this->childObject as $property => $val)
        {
            if (!is_object($this->childObject->{$property}))
            {
                $data[$property] = $val;
            }
        }
        $data['foo'] = $this->foo;
        return $data;
    }
    //and even:
    public function toJson()
    {
        return json_encode($this->toArray());
    }
}
```

Ok, you have to call these methods yourself, explicitly, but that's not that hard, really... is it?

Comment: need to add closing bracket after `$data[property` because it is missing one -- in case someone follows this example for learning :)